# x64 over 50% slower than x86

Tags: c++, visual-c++, x86-64

I am curious why the following code runs significantly slower when targeted to x64.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <chrono>
#include <random>
#include <memory>
#include <climits>
#include "Timer.h"

class Color
{
public:
    union
    {
        unsigned int c;
        struct
        {
            unsigned char b;
            unsigned char g;
            unsigned char r;
            unsigned char x;
        };
    };
public:
    Color()
    {}
    Color( unsigned int c )
        :
        c( c )
    {}
    Color( unsigned char r,unsigned char g,unsigned char b )
        :
        Color( 0u,r,g,b )
    {}
    Color( unsigned char x,unsigned char r,unsigned char g,unsigned char b )
        :
        r( r ),g( g ),b( b ),x( x )
    {}
    Color& operator =( unsigned int c )
    {
        this->c = c;
        return *this;
    }
    operator unsigned int() const
    {
        return c;
    }
};

void RandomizeBuffer( Color* buf,unsigned int width,unsigned int height )
{
    static std::random_device rd;
    static std::mt19937 rng( rd() );
    static std::uniform_int_distribution<unsigned int> dist( 0u,UINT_MAX );

    for( unsigned int i = 0u; i < width * height; i++ )
    {
        buf[i] = dist( rng );
    }
}

void ReduceBuffer( const Color* bufIn,Color* bufOut,unsigned int width,unsigned int height )
{
    for( unsigned int y = 0u; y < height / 4u; y++ )
    {
        for( unsigned int x = 0u; x < width / 4u; x++ )
        {
            const Color p0 =  bufIn[( y * 4u )     * width + x * 4u];
            const Color p1 =  bufIn[( y * 4u )     * width + x * 4u + 1u];
            const Color p2 =  bufIn[( y * 4u )     * width + x * 4u + 2u];
            const Color p3 =  bufIn[( y * 4u )     * width + x * 4u + 3u];
            const Color p4 =  bufIn[( y * 4u + 1u ) * width + x * 4u];
            const Color p5 =  bufIn[( y * 4u + 1u ) * width + x * 4u + 1u];
            const Color p6 =  bufIn[( y * 4u + 1u ) * width + x * 4u + 2u];
            const Color p7 =  bufIn[( y * 4u + 1u ) * width + x * 4u + 3u];
            const Color p8 =  bufIn[( y * 4u + 2u ) * width + x * 4u];
            const Color p9 =  bufIn[( y * 4u + 2u ) * width + x * 4u + 1u];
            const Color p10 = bufIn[( y * 4u + 2u ) * width + x * 4u + 2u];
            const Color p11 = bufIn[( y * 4u + 2u ) * width + x * 4u + 3u];
            const Color p12 = bufIn[( y * 4u + 3u ) * width + x * 4u];
            const Color p13 = bufIn[( y * 4u + 3u ) * width + x * 4u + 1u];
            const Color p14 = bufIn[( y * 4u + 3u ) * width + x * 4u + 2u];
            const Color p15 = bufIn[( y * 4u + 3u ) * width + x * 4u + 3u];

            bufOut[x + y * ( width / 4u )] = Color {
                static_cast<unsigned char>(
                ( p0.r * p0.x + p1.r * p1.x + p2.r * p2.x + p3.r * p3.x + 
                p4.r * p4.x + p5.r * p5.x + p6.r * p6.x + p7.r * p7.x + 
                p8.r * p8.x + p9.r * p9.x + p10.r * p10.x + p11.r * p11.x + 
                p12.r * p12.x + p13.r * p13.x + p14.r * p14.x + p15.r * p15.x ) 
                / ( 16u * 255u ) ),
                static_cast<unsigned char>(
                ( p0.g * p0.x + p1.g * p1.x + p2.g * p2.x + p3.g * p3.x +
                p4.g * p4.x + p5.g * p5.x + p6.g * p6.x + p7.g * p7.x +
                p8.g * p8.x + p9.g * p9.x + p10.g * p10.x + p11.g * p11.x +
                p12.g * p12.x + p13.g * p13.x + p14.g * p14.x + p15.g * p15.x )
                / ( 16u * 255u ) ),
                static_cast<unsigned char>(
                ( p0.b * p0.x + p1.b * p1.x + p2.b * p2.x + p3.b * p3.x +
                p4.b * p4.x + p5.b * p5.x + p6.b * p6.x + p7.b * p7.x +
                p8.b * p8.x + p9.b * p9.x + p10.b * p10.x + p11.b * p11.x +
                p12.b * p12.x + p13.b * p13.x + p14.b * p14.x + p15.b * p15.x )
                / ( 16u * 255u ) )
            };
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    const unsigned int width = 800u;
    const unsigned int height = 600u;
    std::unique_ptr<Color[]> bufFull = std::make_unique<Color[]>( width * height );
    std::unique_ptr<Color[]> bufReduce = std::make_unique<Color[]>( (width / 4u) * (height / 4u) );

    Timer t;
    for( int i = 0; i < 20; i++ )
    {
        RandomizeBuffer( bufFull.get(),width,height );
        t.StartWatch();
        ReduceBuffer( bufFull.get(),bufReduce.get(),width,height );
        t.StopWatch();
        std::cout << t.GetTimeMilli() << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "Press enter to continue..." << std::endl;
    std::getchar();
}
```

The above code executes a single call to `ReduceBuffer()` in about 0.76 ms when compiled as a 32-bit executable, and in about 1.26 ms when compiled as a 64-bit executable.

The compiler is VS2013. Optimization is set to maximize speed and favor fast code. Executed on a Haswell running Win7-x64. The `Timer` class is a simple wrapper for `QueryPerformanceCounter` because VS2013 has a terrible implementation of `high_resolution_clock`

Any insight on why this disparity occurs or even results from other compilers would be greatly welcome.

Comment: Union aliasing causes undefined behaviour in C++. If this is meant to be for a serious application you could rewrite the code to not use union aliasing, and repeat the test.

Comment: It might help to post your Timer (so that others can run your code)

Comment: I suggest to convert `main` to usage of this library https://github.com/google/benchmark your timings is fast enough, to depend on scaling scheduling etc, it would be better to not care about such things

Comment: There could be an issue with 64 bit addressing versus 32-bit addressing.  I suggest printing the assembly language list for both versions and comparing them.

Comment: Union aliasing is used by WIndows API, so Visual Studio shouldn't have issues with it. I don't know if there are issues using 32 bit indexes in 64 bit mode. You could try changing index type from unsigned int to size_t, which will be 32 bits in 32 bit mode and 64 bits in 64 bit mode. Versions of VS prior to VS2015 use the 64hz ticker for chrono high resolution timer. VS2015 is supposed to fix this. I don't know if this is the ticker than can be set to 1khz using timeBeginPeriod().  QueryPerformanceCounter should have a frequency well over 1 mega-hertz, so it's OK to use.

Comment: @rcgldr: 32bit indices don't hurt much if at all.  Sign-extending 32 to 64 just takes one fast instruction (`movsx`).  If the compiler can prove that a value is positive (or if the type is unsigned), then no extra work is needed.  (writing a 32b register zeroes the upper32).  The only time a compiler needs to emit an insn to zero-extend 32->64 is for function parameters in registers.  In *that* case it can't assume the upper32 are zeroed.

Comment: @chili: Post the ASM for both 32 and 64bit, so we can see what it's doing.  I don't see anything at all obvious.  1 ms is not a very big time window, but if those numbers are reproducible, there's probably something significant different in the asm.  I don't have MSVC, so I can't test anything.  Is `sizeof(Color)` the same for both?  Is it auto-vectorizing with SSE4.2 and/or AVX2 for either or both x86 and x86-64 targets?  If you're using perf counters anyway, what's it bottlenecking on?  memory or CPU core?  How many instructions (or fused-domain uops) per cycle?

Comment: To compile without your "Timer.h", I just commented that stuff out, and too the rng out of the timing loop, so it just happens once at the start.  I increased the iterations from 20 to 2000.  On an Intel SnB (3.7GHz turbo), the whole program takes **gcc5.2 64b** ~6.3B cycles (1.7sec) 2.66 insn/clock.  **gcc5.2 32b** ~5.1B cycles (1.4sec), 2.51 insn/clock.  `g++ -O3 -march=native`.  So 32bit code uses fewer instructions and is faster with gcc as well.  (but only by a 1.7/1.4 = 1.2, not 50%.  Haswell has mov-elimination and a 4th integer execution port, so our CPUs are different.).

Comment: @PeterCordes Hey peter thanks for taking a look at this. Here are the disassemblies for both builds: [32-bit](http://pastebin.com/2RTjzVMK) [64-bit](http://pastebin.com/j0V0Qa6Y)

Comment: @chili: I already spent a while looking at gcc's output, and now my brain hurts.  I was just going to say that if you want this to run fast, you can probably get a big speedup with SSE/AVX instructions.  gcc is doing *lots* of byte load / store, and lots of 32bit imul and add.  SSE has some instructions that are pretty special-purpose for graphics.  A packed format (array of structs) isn't ideal compared to a planar format (struct of arrays), but the shuffling required to apply the alpha to the other three components is still worth it.

Comment: I see similarities between gcc and MSVC output.  In both, the 64bit asm is loading pointers sometimes.  IDK why it ever stored pointers, and to what.  Actually, the 32bit version is doing that too, but they don't stand out because they're just dwords (32bit) not qwords, so the pointers are the same size as other things being loaded and stored.  Maybe it's doing an address calculation and then spilling it to memory, because of lack of registers?  Maybe a different order of operations, and some local variables to accumulate things, would produce better asm?  e.g. do everything for one row.

Comment: @PeterCordes Already there friend, and it's about 500% faster ;) [SSSE3](http://pastebin.com/cttnABAe). This is all academic anyways, as the best place for this work is the GPU. I was just surprised at the poor x64 performance.  Also, I see that when I roll my own SSE implementation using intrinsics, there is little difference between x86/x64 (x64 has the edge here, probably because of the extra xmm registers. Using VEX helps too.)

Comment: Ok, yeah, I agree it's an interesting academic question.  I don't know why the 64bit code seems to have more `mov` instructions mixed in with the movzx / imul / add insns, but gcc's output looks that way to me.  Profiling shows more total instructions for the same work with 64b (and I'm guessing they're `mov` insns), but like I said, I haven't sorted out *why* gcc emits what it does.  There's too much code to really grok without spending days on it, even with the help of [godbolt colour highlighting](http://goo.gl/rSYzHN).

Comment: @PeterCordes No worries, thanks for taking a look. I'm satisfied that it's just a compiler issue and not an inherent weakness in x64 architecture in general or Haswell's implementation specifically.

Comment: gcc and msvc both show it.  However, clang++-3.8 times at 1.75s (**64b**) vs. 2.35s (**32b**), so clang does much worse with fewer registers.  I don't think 64bit imposes anything that would require more instructions.  Maybe gcc keeps more stuff in registers, but has to do more `mov`s to manage it?  I *think* it's just a trap the compiler's falling into, rather than a 32bit-temporary vs. 64bit addresses problem.  I assume if I wrote non-vector asm that an ideal compiler might produce for that source, I could write at least slightly faster code for x86-64 than for x86-32.